# Nested Documents in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Mongoose schemas, User and Code. Each user can have many codes.

user.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var codeSchema = require('./code');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    google: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String
    },

    codes: [codeSchema]
}, {collection : 'users'});
```

code.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var codeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    code: String,
    name: String,
    link: String
}, {collection: 'codes'});

module.exports = codeSchema;
```

My problem is, whenever I access a user's array of codes by `user.codes`, I get something like `{ _id: 56c4c82a37273dc2b756a0ce },{ _id: 56c4c82a37273dc2b756a0cd }` rather than the JSON for a code.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you add an indexed `userId` field to `codes`? Then you can find all codes from that collection by the `userId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, turns out I was using the wrong dataset, not adding the codes properly (facepalm). Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `populate`.

By default, Mongoose will only give you the _ids of any references made in a document. `populate` allows you to fill out nested documents.

`userSchema.findOne({}).populate('codes');`

More [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
please check that you are inserting other values or not this can be a case . Please write how you are inserting in array . I have two other way check out

There are two way to do this  
1-->either you save refrence id of codeschema and 
2--> is you can insert whole codeschema in array

1. codes: {
        type: mongooseSchema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'codeSchema',
        required: true
    },

and when all data is in array 56c4c82a37273dc2b756a0ce,56c4c82a37273dc2b756a0cd

that can be done by this query 
domain.User.update({_id:id}
              ,{$addToSet:{code:codeObjvalue}},
               function(err,res){});

and then populate them by this 
 domain.users.find({},'code')
               .populate('code','code color email').
               exec(function(err,results){
        callback(err, results);
    });


2-- and second is to insert whole code schema in userschema


create a codeschema object and add in set like this
var codeobj={};
codeobj.code="xyz";
codeobj.email="xyz@gmail.com"
var codeobject = new domain.code(codeobj);
    domain.User.update({_id:id},{$addToSet:{code:codeobject}},function(err,user1){
    });
```